# Drawing a hollow circle without a line border

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, 2d, pixi.js

Has anyone got experience on drawing a hollow circle with Pixi?, my current approach only works in the WebGL renderer which makes me think it's flawed, and i also need to fallback to the other rendered for other devices.

```
this.mathPiDub = 2 * Math.PI;
this.color = 0xFF00FF
var nuRad = 10;
this.pixiCircle.beginFill(this.color, 1);
this.pixiCircle.arc(0, 0, nuRad - 2, 0, this.mathPiDub, false);
this.pixiCircle.arc(0, 0, nuRad, 0, this.mathPiDub, false);
this.pixiCircle.endFill();
```

The 2D rendered gives me a full circle while the WebGL cuts the hole through.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way would be to use the built in `drawCircle()` with a `lineStyle` instead of a fill.

```
this.pixiCircle = new PIXI.Graphics();
this.pixiCircle.lineStyle(2, 0xFF00FF);  //(thickness, color)
this.pixiCircle.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);   //(x,y,radius)
this.pixiCircle.endFill(); 
stage.addChild(this.pixiCircle);
```

This will work for both WebGL and Canvas renderers

Answer (score 4):

If you are using version 5, you can use the beginHole() and endHole() methods.

```js
function createHollowCircle(radius, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) {

  let circle = new Graphics();
  circle.beginFill(color);
  circle.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
  circle.beginHole();
  circle.drawCircle(0, 0, radius - 0.1);
  circle.endHole();
  circle.endFill();
  circle.x = x_coordinate;
  circle.y = y_coordinate;
  return circle;
  
}
```

[Hollow Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ14w.png)